# Using MCN_GETDAYSTATE event handler and dynamic MONTHDAYSTATE arrays causing errors

Tags: mfc, monthcalendar

Here is an interesting problem that I have encountered. I have used the [`MCN_GETDAYSTATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760935(v=vs.85).aspx) event handler with my `CMonthCalendarControl` for several years with no problems. The handler looks like this:

```
void CHomeAwayMaintPage::OnGetDayStateCalendar(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    NMDAYSTATE      *pDayState = (NMDAYSTATE*)pNMHDR;
    MONTHDAYSTATE   mdState[3]; // last, this, next
    COleDateTime    datStart(pDayState->stStart);

    if (pDayState != nullptr)
    {
        InitDayStateArray(pDayState->cDayState, mdState, datStart);
        pDayState->prgDayState = mdState;
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

It has always worked fine. The calendar in the window looks like this:

[image: Calendar]

Now, over the last two days I have upgraded this window to support resizing and as such I have setup the calendar to resize. Example:

[image: MultipleCalendar]

I adjusted the event handler (since we have potentially any number of calendars) like this:

```
void CHomeAwayMaintPage::OnGetDayStateCalendar(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    NMDAYSTATE      *pDayState = (NMDAYSTATE*)pNMHDR;
    COleDateTime    datStart(pDayState->stStart);

    DWORD dwCount = MonthCal_GetMonthRange(m_Calender.GetSafeHwnd(), GMR_DAYSTATE, NULL);
    MONTHDAYSTATE *pmdState = new MONTHDAYSTATE[dwCount];

    if (pDayState != nullptr)
    {
        InitDayStateArray(pDayState->cDayState, pmdState, datStart);
        pDayState->prgDayState = pmdState;
    }

    delete[] pmdState;

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Yet, when I shut the window down VS2017 is raising this error:

[image: Error 1]

I tried to comment out the `delete[] pmdState;` line and that made no difference. I am also getting this error quite regularly when trying to display the window:

[image: Error 2]

If I reset the dynamic layout for the calendar control to just move the control and not resize it (so one one month is visible) and revert my day state event handler back to what it was previously, these two errors go away and it becomes stable like before.

So what am I doing wrong here?

## Update

This is the `InitDayStateArray` method. Just reads the database:

```
void CHomeAwayMaintPage::InitDayStateArray(int iMonthCount,
     LPMONTHDAYSTATE pDayState, COleDateTime datStart)
{
    int                 iStartMonth, iLastMonth, iThisMonth, iMonth = 0;
    COleDateTime        datDay;
    COleDateTimeSpan    spnDay;
    CString             strDate;
    SCHEDULE_DATA_S     *psTalk = NULL;
    S_JOURNAL_ITEM      *psJournal = NULL; // AJT v11.2.0

    if (pDayState != NULL)
    {
        memset(pDayState, 0, sizeof(MONTHDAYSTATE)*iMonthCount);

        spnDay.SetDateTimeSpan(1,0,0,0);

        datDay = datStart;
        iStartMonth = datStart.GetMonth();
        iThisMonth = iStartMonth;
        iLastMonth = iThisMonth;
        do 
        {
            strDate.Format(_T("%d-%02d-%02d"),
                datDay.GetYear(),
                datDay.GetMonth(),
                datDay.GetDay());

            // try to get this entry from map
            psTalk = NULL;
            m_mapSPTalkDates.Lookup(strDate, (void*&)psTalk);
            if (psTalk != NULL && psTalk->uTalkNumber != 1000)
                BOLDDAY(pDayState[iMonth], datDay.GetDay());

            // AJT v11.2.0
            strDate = datDay.Format(_T("%Y-%m-%d"));
            psJournal = NULL;
            m_mapStrPtrJournalCalendar.Lookup(strDate, (void*&)psJournal);
            if (psJournal != NULL)
                BOLDDAY(pDayState[iMonth], datDay.GetDay());

            datDay = datDay + spnDay;
            iThisMonth = datDay.GetMonth();
            if (iThisMonth != iLastMonth)
            {
                iLastMonth = iThisMonth;
                iMonth++;
            }
        } while(iMonth < iMonthCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `InitDayStateArray`? And the rest of the code to produce MCVE? I have never seen this before when Windows shows debug messages about a program which finished earlier.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani That is my method which reads my database to determine what the bit values should be in the array. And I don’t mean about when the program finishes, I mean when the property sheet is closed. It also happens if I maximise the property sheet. I would have to prepare a MCVE as this is a program over 10 years old. I think we just need to put the calendar on a test dialog and resize it. Add support for setting day states and try maximise. It seems to be related to how I am allocating the memory for the day state array. Will do test project later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `DWORD dwCount = MonthCal_GetMonthRange(m_Calender.GetSafeHwnd(), GMR_DAYSTATE, NULL);`

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774701(v=vs.85).aspx) says that the third parameter cannot be `NULL`:

> Pointer to a two-element array of `SYSTEMTIME` structures that will receive the lower and upper limits of the scope specified by dwFlag. The lower and upper limits are placed in `lprgSysTimeArray[0]` and `lprgSysTimeArray[1]`, respectively. The time members of these structures will not be modified. This parameter must be a valid address and cannot be `NULL`.

When running your code, I get `dwCount = 4` and `pDayState->cDayState = 395234`

Result:

```
MONTHDAYSTATE *pmdState = new MONTHDAYSTATE[4];
...
InitDayStateArray(...)
{
    iMonthCount = pDayState->cDayState
    pDayState = pmdState;
    memset(pDayState, 0, sizeof(MONTHDAYSTATE)*395234);
    ...
}
```

Note that `memset` is causing buffer overrun by the amount `(395234 - 4) * sizeof(MONTHDAYSTATE)` This can cause serious problems.

You can rewrite the code as follows:

```
void CHomeAwayMaintPage::OnMcnSelchangeMonthcalendar1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    SYSTEMTIME systime[2];
    int month_count = MonthCal_GetMonthRange(m_Calender.GetSafeHwnd(),
            GMR_DAYSTATE, &systime);
    std::vector<MONTHDAYSTATE> vec(month_count); //or use new/delete

    COleDateTime date(systime[0]);
    COleDateTime end(systime[1]);
    COleDateTimeSpan spnDay;
    spnDay.SetDateTimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
    while (date < end)
    {
        CString str = date.Format(_T("%Y-%m-%d"));
        TRACE(_T("datDay %s\n"), str.GetString());
        date = date + spnDay;
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

---

## Update

Based on the above answer (thank you) and those in the comments here I was able to simplify my event handler and do it correctly:

```
void CHomeAwayMaintPage::OnGetDayStateCalendar(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
    NMDAYSTATE *pDayState = (NMDAYSTATE*)pNMHDR;

    if (pDayState != nullptr)
        InitDayStateArray(pDayState->cDayState, 
            pDayState->prgDayState, COleDateTime(pDayState->stStart));

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/) it says:

> "it receives the address of an array that provides this data."

I was getting confused by [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms936810.aspx) where you do have to set the buffer.

As you can see, the structure passed in already has a buffer allocated. I just had to tweak the values. No memory allocation anywhere.

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining the problem. With further research of `NMDAYSTATE ` I corrected my code. All OK now.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: That looks like a use-after-free bug. You are assigning `pmdState` to an out parameter and then move on to delete it. Before the caller has had a chance to read it. This should be very visible in a debug build, where `operator delete[]` uses a particular fill pattern (0xDD).

Comment: @IInspectable as Barmak mentioned, when I was using `MonthCal_GetMonthRange` incorrectly and thus creating a buffer with an undefined value which blew up the system. In the end I did not even have to use that macro because `pDayState->cDayState` already tells me how many months we need to create an array for. As soon I used the macro correctly (or in the end simplified the code) the errors went away.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: But there *is* a bug. You are passing a pointer to an array to the caller and then delete it, before returning control to the caller. I'm not sure whether this is a documentation bug, and the system already allocates a buffer for you to fill. If this weren't the case, I cannot see any conceivable way to construct that buffer with appropriate lifetime, without leaking memory. Out of curiosity: What's the value of `pDayState->prgDayState` on entry? Is it a non-null value?

Comment: It is not null. I see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760935(v=vs.85).aspx it says "it receives the address of an array that provides this data." I was getting confused by this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms936810.aspx. I have modified my handler to just use the buffer passed in and not delete it! Thanks.